# Is using selenium in a MapReduce job a good use for Hadoop?

Tags: java, selenium, hadoop

I am doing a project using hadoop that collects tweets from various twitter accounts using selenium. Instead of doing one after the other, I would like to do them concurrently using hadoop to decrease the collection time. Does this sound doable and would it be a good use of hadoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter has a streaming API which you can use to get constant stream of tweets and load them to HDFS and use any of the processing frameworks (Hive, storm, spark) to make sense out of those tweets. There are packaged tools available if you don't want to code using twitter API's you can use Apache NiFi or Flume to source tweets for you and load them to HDFS.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.twitter.GetTwitter/

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/09/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop/